# Image path on ASP.NET doesn't work

Tags: .net, image, iis, publish

Image path on publish project in **ASP.NET** doesn't work.

This is my image path: `var imgSrc = "~/Images/Markers";`

In Markers folder, I have icons that I want to display depending on the logged-in user. It works fine on local but it's not working when I publish the project on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

**Two reasons for that :**
1. give path like "/Images/Markers" instead of "~/Images/Markers".
 OR
2. check at published directory image is exist or not,some time after publish image not copied so.